# How to pause and resume reading with Netty 4?

Tags: netty

In Netty 3 we can do:

```
Channel.setReadable(false);
Channel.setReadable(true);
```

I've read:
http://netty.io/news/2012/09/13/4-0-0-alpha4.html

But with the latest Netty 4 version (4.0.17, http://netty.io/news/2014/02/25/4-0-17-Final.html), this code is invalid because there's no `ChannelHandlerContext#readable`:

```
serverChannel.pipeline().firstContext().readable(false);
serverChannel.pipeline().firstContext().readable(true);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use to pause:

```
channel.config.setAutoRead(false)
```

and to resume:

```
channel.config.setAutoRead(true)
```

Comment: If you are using some message decoder, It will not pause immediatly.